# can't update (or write continuously) counter in ther form's textbox

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm intermediate c++ programmer. But new to Visual Studio GUI programming. Please believe me that I really searched previous errors that other user's also get, but really cant go on further. Thank u very much for further help.

I just want to see a continuous counter in small screen. When I push the Start button the counter must start until the Stop button is pushed.

I debug the forms project the window is shown but when I press the Start button I get the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I tried also the choice of code part in /*   */ but again I cant do what I want.

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

int formcounter, xx;

#pragma once

namespace denemeform {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            formcounter=0;
        }

    protected:
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();

            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(27, 24);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"&Start";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);

            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(166, 24);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button2->Text = L"Sto&p";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);

            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(82, 71);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;

            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(269, 139);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();
        }
#pragma endregion

        void Test() //test code:: when "Start" is pushed, this code is what executes
        {
            int formcounter=0; //test variable

            while(xx) 
            {
                formcounter++;
                this->textBox1->Text = formcounter.ToString(); //sets first textbox to 'a'
                Sleep(100); //pause for 1 second before continuing
            }
                /*formcounter++;
                if (this->InvokeRequired)
                this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &Form1::Test));
            else
                this->textBox1->Text = formcounter.ToString();
                Sleep(1000);*/
        }

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        xx=1;
        /*Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Form1::Test ) );
        oThread->Start();*/
        Thread^ tThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::Test));
        tThread->Start();
    }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        xx=0;
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what happens when you use the commented out code, but I believe I see what's going on.

You do need to use InvokeRequired & `this->Invoke`, but you're passing the wrong thing to `this->Invoke`. You're passing a method with a loop in it (Form1::Test), and it isn't returning. You should pass a delegate that just sets the text box once.

Try moving `formcounter` to be a class field instead of a local variable, and do something like this:

```
bool xx;
int formcounter;

void SetTextBoxOnce()
{
    this->textBox1->Text = formcounter->ToString();
}

void TestThread()
{
    this->formcounter = 0;
    while(xx)
    {
        this->formcounter++;
        // We're running on a newly created thread, we know that we ALWAYS need to Invoke.
        this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &Form1::SetTextBoxOnce));
        Thread::Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't managed yet. I think I gotta learn first "how to"'s for Event Handling and running  asynchronous events.

Comment: Thanks God. Thank you very much David Yaw.

Answer (score 2):

The code now executes correctly.

```
void SetTextBoxOnce()
{
    this->textBox1->Text = formcounter.ToString(); 
}

void Test()  
{
    formcounter=0; //test variable

    while(xx) 
    {
        formcounter++;
    this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &Form1::SetTextBoxOnce));
        Sleep(100);  
        }
    }

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    xx=1;
    Thread^ tThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::Test));
    tThread->Start();
}
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    xx=0;
}
```

The code now executes correctly.